# Dynamically add CSS to the visual editor

Tags: visual-editor, css

I created an options page for my theme, where I can manually edit the CSS.
Lets say I change the CSS in the options page for the `<H1>` tag, so it will now change it on the front-end.
What I want to also do is have it change in the visual editor.

I have added the function

```
add_editor_style(style.php);
```

and in the `style.php` I have it saying in the top

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/css');
?>
```

so it recognizes the file. But now I can't get the options dynamically...

How should I achieve this?

EDIT

this is in the functions.

```
add_filter( 'mce_css', 'cnote_visual_css' );
function cnote_visual_css() {
    return get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/cnotethegr8/global-style.php';
}
```

this is the global stylesheet

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/css');
global $shortname;
?>

h1 { <?php echo(get_option($shortname.'_style_h1')); ?> }
```

when i echo $shortname nothing shows...

Comment: Do you have a problem loading that `style.css` file in the editor, or do you have a problem reading your plugin settings in that file? Can you edit your question to make this clear?

Comment: Could this be due to tiny mce and your browser caching the old stylesheet? Maybe try adding a random generated number to `add_editor_style("style.php?v=".rand());`

Comment: @Brady: So i thought it was to the version generator, but i fixed that problem. Basically the php options arent being recognized. For instance if i echo get_bloginfo('name') nothing is printed. but the php itself does work with a test of $this = 'hello'; echo $this;

Comment: Ok I think I might know your answer but need to see your code to say for certain. Please post your dynamic stylesheet code as the way you think it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this isn't working is because the WordPress core isn't loaded when this dynamic style sheet is loaded. `get_option()` hasn't been defined yet.

What you need to do is load WordPress at the top of your dynamic stylesheet:

```
<?php
include("../../../wp-load.php");
?>
```